# Simple p5.js shader on a sphere

Tags: shader, p5.js

I'm pretty new to writing shaders and am having a hard time figuring out what I think should be a very simple thing to do in p5js with the samples I'm copying from.  [This](https://editor.p5js.org/JasonGoemaat/sketches/WE3dECRA7) (adapted from [this](https://editor.p5js.org/kjhollen/sketches/rJGMUhh0G)) is what I'm working on.   It has an image that has uv coordinates and a grid and got it working with both a rect and a sphere:

```js
  texture(img);
  // shader(theShader);

  rect(-width/2, -height/2, width, height);
  sphere(380);
```

[image: Texture]

I want to do something more complex, but to start with I'm trying to just create a shader that returns a single color.   I just don't think they're being used.   If I comment out the texture line and uncomment the shader line, I get a plain white sphere and rectangle:

[image: bad]

Here is my vertex shader (though I've tried a lot of things):

```c
attribute vec2 a_position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(a_position * 0.2, 0, 1);
}
```

And current fragment shader (though I've tried a lot of things):

```c
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

That is just the current state, trying to make it as simple as possible.  I've tried adding in the uv texture coordinates and texture and returning a different color, but to no avail.  I've tried so many things by now I almost think they just aren't being used.  Removing the layer and stroking I find that there is a rectangle of that color being created, in addition to the 3d rectangle, so is the shader completely separate from the 3d model?

Looking at [this example](https://editor.p5js.org/JasonGoemaat/sketches/fwYHR1r9w) I created [this](https://editor.p5js.org/JasonGoemaat/sketches/bzu_Wqqpk) which does color my object, but that seems to be creating new texture object and using the shader to fill in the texture.  That is not what I want at all.   What I want is for p5 to give me a value from 0 to 1 for uv like the texture image, with as much precision as it can, and to return a color based on whatever values I have for uv.  I'm just really confused.  I don't even want to do anything in my vertex shader, I want P5 to pass everything from the sphere it creates to my fragment shader.  It seems like this is rendering the shader to a texture and applying that texture to the objects, I don't want to use a texture at all.

```c
  shaderTexture.shader(theShader);
  shaderTexture.rect(0, 0, width, height);
  texture(shaderTexture);
```

I'm trying to get some kind of foundation and start with the simplest thing I can, maybe I'm reaching too far trying to use 3d shapes created by p5?

Comment: I just played around with it and couldn't get it to work either. Either the shaders don't work as documented and don't work with the geometries like spheres or there is just huge bug in p5.js.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there was a lot more to get it working than I thought :).  There is some behind the scenes work going on and if your shaders aren't setup correctly, the default shaders are used.

1. If you have lighting enabled, there is quite a list of attributes and uniforms that P5 will pass and that *must* exist on your compiled shader.  If your shader doesn't contain these, P5 will use a default P5 shader instead and not tell you.  Check out [p5.RendererGL.js](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/webgl/p5.RendererGL.js) (`_getRetainedFillShader` is one function in a chain of selecting what shader to use)
2. There are a lot of if statements and shader types along with default set, I might be missing something else.   There are default fill, texture, and light shaders I think.

To get around this, checkout [an updated p5 sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/JasonGoemaat/sketches/vkIeEkc9q).   I had took [P5's phong.vert](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/webgl/shaders/phong.vert) and had to combine [lighting.glsl](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/webgl/shaders/lighting.glsl)
and [phong.frag](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/webgl/shaders/phong.frag)
to create the fragment shader.

Doing this made it work just like normal using lighting and the texture I set, but I could then tweak the shaders to my liking.  The vertex shader *has* to do some positioning using values passed by P5 and set the properties for the vertex anyway to get meaningful values in the fragment shader.